# ffmpeg Error when trying to concatenate 2 parts with different speed

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatanate to parts of the same input video but one is speeded up 20x. The code I'm using is this:

```
ffmpeg -i 7.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]select='between(t,0,9)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vn];[0:a]aselect='between(t,0,9)',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[an];[0:v]select='between(t,191,1174)',setpts=(1/20)*(PTS-STARTPTS)[vr];[0:a]aselect='between(t,191,1174)',atempo=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ar];[vn][an][vr][ar]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -crf 23 -preset slow "output5.mp4"
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong, about the can't allocat memory part I have 16 GB of memory and only running ffmpeg....

Errors:

```
[h264 @ 00000181d923ccc0] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 00000181d923ccc0] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 00000181d923ccc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000181d923ccc0] no frame!
[fc#0 @ 00000181d91dbdc0] Task finished with error code: -12 (Cannot allocate memory)peed=0.0342x
[fc#0 @ 00000181d91dbdc0] Terminating thread with return code -12 (Cannot allocate memory)
[vist#0:0/h264 @ 00000181db1bbcc0] [dec:h264 @ 00000181d91e4680] Error submitting packet to decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Try using the same input file twice. Example: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]select='between(t,0,9)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vn];[1:v]select='between(t,191,1174)',setpts=(1/20)*(PTS-STARTPTS)[vr];[vn][vr]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[vid]" -map "[vid]" -c:v libx264 -preset fast output.mp4`. Please consider posting minimal reproducible example. Audio part seems irrelevant. Consider adding instruction for generating an input file that reproduces the issue like: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=10000 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4`

Comment: What would be different if I use the same input twice?

Comment: When concatenating two parts of the same input, I think there are cases when FFmpeg stores many decoded frames in memory (buffering frames). The buffering purpose is for avoid decoding the same frames multiple times. When using the same input twice, each input is decoded separately (avoid buffering). I am not sure about the buffering mechanism, but it might explain the "Cannot allocate memory" error.

Comment: Thank you, if you want to put your comments as answer I will accept it. The first time I tried this the computer restarted (don't think it's related) but then it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in FFmpeg, that is related to concatenating a video with itself.
Possible workaround is using the same input file twice (as if it were two input files):

`ffmpeg -i 7.mp4 -i 7.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]select='between(t,0,9)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vn];[0:a]aselect='between(t,0,9)',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[an];[1:v]select='between(t,191,1174)',setpts=(1/20)*(PTS-STARTPTS)[vr];[1:a]aselect='between(t,191,1174)',atempo=20,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ar];[vn][an][vr][ar]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -crf 23 -preset slow "output5.mp4"`

---

The following expiation is just a guess:
When concatenating two parts of the same input, I think there are cases when FFmpeg stores many decoded frames in memory (buffering frames). The buffering purpose is for avoid decoding the same frames multiple times. When using the same input twice, each input is decoded separately (avoid buffering). I am not sure about the buffering mechanism, but it might explain the "Cannot allocate memory" error.